# Infinitely many beta functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Had to compute this sum in order to finish solving an integral (Couldn't find another way). I tried converting it to gamma functions and trying to use some identities but did make any progress. Typing it in wolfram alpha would give me $2\pi ln(1/2 + 1/\sqrt2)$ which is indeed the correct answer, but I'm interested in seeing a complete proof of the sum. Any help is appreciated, cheers! 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}B(n+1/2,1/2)}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of the Beta function we have

$$B[k + 1/2, 1/2] = \frac{\Gamma\left[k + \frac{1}{2}\right]\Gamma\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]}{\Gamma[k+1]}$$

Now we make use of elementary definition for the Gamma function, as $k \in \mathbb{N}$:

. $\Gamma[1/2] = \sqrt{\pi}$

. $\Gamma[k+1] = k\Gamma[k] = k!$

. $\Gamma\left[k + \frac{1}{2}\right] = \frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k}\sqrt{\pi}$

Substituting in the sum and we get

$$\pi \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k\cdot k!} \frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k}$$

**I'll write further edits later**

Comment: Thank you very much! Sadly, I’m still unable to get anything out of the new sum, though :(

Comment: @coque Hey, sorry for my delay! I will add more details tomorrow!!